# Logging raspberry pi temperature in Ubuntu - trouble running .sh script

Tags: shell-script

I have a raspberry pi 4 with Ubuntu 20.04 installed.  I'm new to linux and trying to log the temperature of the raspberry pi every few minutes.

I wrote a .sh file that I am trying to run but is not working right and I am not sure why.

```
#!/bin/bash
temp=$(/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
temp_f=echo "$temp/1000" | bc -l
echo "Pi Temp: %.3fC\n" $temp_f >> /home/projects/temperature_logger/temp.log
```

When I try running this I get

```
./logscript.sh: line 2: /sys/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp: Permission Denied
./logscript.sh: line 3: /1000: No such file or directory
./logscript.sh: line 4: /home/projects/temperature_logger/temp.log: Permission Denied
```

How can I resolve these permission issues?  I am logged in as ubuntu who is the only user on this pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 1st line tries to execute `/sys/.../temp`. That is not what you want. Use `cat` or `head -n 1` to retrieve the value
  in that file.
- 2nd line lacks the `$()` construct to evaluate the command and store its output.
- 3rd line complains about permission. You need write permission to the `temp.log` file, which can be granted with `chmod ugo+w temp.log`.

I have also replaced `echo` by `printf` as [the latter is more reliable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) and in the last line that is how you truncate the value to three decimal places.

```
temp=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
temp_f=$(printf '%s\n' "$temp/1000" | bc -l)
printf 'Pi Temp: %.3fC\n' "$temp_f" >> /home/projects/temperature_logger/temp.log
```